# The indefinite integral $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln(x+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to get my head around calculating
$$
\int\frac{1}{x\ln(x+1)}dx.
$$
I can't seem to get anywhere. I tried parts and substitutions, but that $(x+1)$ is always in the way.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to all those who have pointed out that there is no simple expression for the integral.
Does anyone know a closed-form approximation? I'm not interested in a definite integral, but rather in an approximation to
$$
\int_1^x\frac{1}{t\ln(t+1)}dt.
$$

Comment: This integral is actually not computable if you check [Wolfram Mathematica](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1%2F%28xln%28x+%2B+1%29%29&random=false).

Comment: Mathematica 8 returns this unevaluated.

Comment: Fairly often an antiderivative cannot be expressed in terms of the standard elementary functions. Some evidence that this might be the case in particular instance can be obtained by asking Wolfram Alpha, or Mathematica, or Maple to do it.

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical approximation over a given interval?

Comment: I suppose $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t \ln(t+1)} \; dt$ is not a satisfactory answer here.

Comment: How large should be $x$ ?

Comment: Really I'd like a good approximation up to $x=10^6$.

Comment: For $x > 10$ or so, I think $\int_1^x{{dt\over t \ln{\!(t+1)}}}$ is not much different from $\int_1^{10}{{dt\over t \ln{\!(t+1)}}} + \int_{10}^x{{dt\over t \ln{t}}} \approx 1.78252+ \ln\!{(\ln{x}/\ln{10})}$.

Comment: I will post the above because I see it says to refrain from answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\ln(x+1)$ ,

Then $x=e^u-1$

$dx=e^u~du$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{1}{x\ln(x+1)}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{e^u}{u(e^u-1)}du$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{u(1-e^{-u})}du$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB_nu^{n-2}}{n!}du$ (with the formula in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function)

$=\int\left(\dfrac{1}{u^2}-\dfrac{1}{2u}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB_nu^{n-2}}{n!}\right)du$

$=-\dfrac{1}{u}-\dfrac{\ln u}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB_nu^{n-1}}{n!(n-1)}+C$

$=-\dfrac{1}{\ln(x+1)}-\dfrac{\ln\ln(x+1)}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB_n(\ln(x+1))^{n-1}}{n!(n-1)}+C$

$\therefore\int_1^x\dfrac{1}{t\ln(t+1)}dx$

$=\left[-\dfrac{1}{\ln(t+1)}-\dfrac{\ln\ln(t+1)}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB_n(\ln(t+1))^{n-1}}{n!(n-1)}\right]_1^x$

$=\dfrac{1}{\ln2}-\dfrac{1}{\ln(x+1)}+\dfrac{\ln\ln2}{2}-\dfrac{\ln\ln(x+1)}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB_n((\ln(x+1))^{n-1}-(\ln2)^{n-1})}{n!(n-1)}$

Answer (score 2):

Choose a number $N$ that is relatively large, like 10 or 20 or what have you, and then you might try $$\int_1^x{{dt\over t \ln\!{(t+1)}}} \approx \int_1^N{dt\over t\ln\!(t+1)} + \int_N^x{dt\over t\ln t}\qquad \qquad (x \geq N)$$ The first integral on the right-hand side can be evaluated numerically given the choice of $N$, and the second integral is $\ln\!{(\ln{x}/\ln{N})}$.

So for example, the choice $N = 20$ leads to the following approximation for $x \geq 20$: $$\int_1^x{{dt\over t \ln\!{(t+1)}}} \approx 0.9415 + \ln\!{(\ln{x}})\,.$$

Comment: Nice! This might work!

Comment: If you want to use $N = 100$, I made a table of values for the integral for $x = 1$ to $x = 100$. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqbnrxysq100oz2/DataTable.csv

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the asymptotics of the function $$
\int_1^x \frac{1}{t\log(1+t)} dt
$$
for large $x$, one good way to approximate it is to observe that $\frac1t \approx \frac1{1+t}$. In fact $$
\frac1t = \frac1{1+t}+\frac1{t(1+t)}
$$
so \begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^x \frac{1}{t\log(1+t)} dt &=& \int_1^x \frac{1}{(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt + \int_1^x \frac{1}{t(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt \\
&=& \log(\log(1+x))-\log(\log(2))+\int_1^x \frac{1}{t(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt
\end{eqnarray}
Note that the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt$ converges to about $0.5715$. Thus we have $$
\int_1^x \frac{1}{t\log(1+t)} dt = \log \log(1+x) -\log \log 2 + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt + o(1)
$$

With an estimate on $\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{t(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt$ you can get a tighter asymptotic than $o(1)$, for example $$
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{t(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt}{\frac{1}{x\log x}} = 1
$$
gives us $$
\int_1^x \frac{1}{t\log(1+t)} dt = \log \log(1+x) -\log \log 2 + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t(1+t)\log(1+t)} dt-\frac1{x\log x} + o\left(\frac1{x\log x}\right)
$$

You can proceed likewise to get tighter asymptotics.